# Filetable size vs database size in sql server

Tags: sql-server

If I create a FileTable in SQL server 2012, and then was to drop a 4G file onto the NT filesystem (that was in the filestream), would that entire 4G file be read into the table's filestream column?

Is SQL in fact making a COPY of my 4G file? Or does the filestream column represent a pointer to my 4G file, which it begins to read on a query?

Im just trying to figure out if I added 100G of data to my file system, would that add 100G of data size to my DB.

Can someone help explain how this works? And even better point me to some docs with more detail than the MS/MSDN 'how-to' stuff?

Comment: Just I need to understand how  datbase size varies w.r.t Filetable size in sql server.
and I deleted 100 MB data from Filetable path , but there is no change in database size . how it works .. please help me understanding .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The file table stream is stored separately in individual files using the SQL Server `FILESTREAM` feature, not in the normal SQL Server data files.  These files are managed internally by SQL Server.

You can consider the file_stream column similarly to a pointer to the file.  The file stream is still part of the database, though, and will be backed up along with the rest of the database.

Answer (score 0):

No, your 4 Gb file will be stored only once, as a file on disk. Sure, there will be some small amount of metadata stored in the database, but that's all.

[MDSN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929144.aspx).